# XmlSerializer sample from MSDN fails

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xmlserializer

I am trying to learn how to use XMLSerializer. I created a VS2010 project using the sample code on: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tz8csy73(v=vs.100).aspx.

The code is supposed to deserialize a simple XML document into a simple C# object. It compiles and runs without error, but fails to restore the C# object. All fields remain either 0 or null.

I have .NET Framework 4.0 as required by the sample. I put a breakpoint on the last Console.Write and can see that all values are 0 or null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the XML file in the sample.  The names of the elements are prefixed with an XML namespace and that's causing the serializer to not map them to the raw fields in the `OrderedItem` type.  If you remove the namespaces in the XML file this sample will run correctly.

Alternatively you can decorate the `OrderedItem` type to contain the proper namespaces used in the simple.xml file

```
public class OrderedItem
{
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://www.cpandl.com")]
    public string ItemName;
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://www.cpandl.com")]
    public string Description;
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://www.cohowinery.com")]
    public decimal UnitPrice;
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://www.cpandl.com")]
    public int Quantity;
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://www.cohowinery.com")]
    public decimal LineTotal;

    // A custom method used to calculate price per item.
    public void Calculate()
    {
        LineTotal = UnitPrice * Quantity;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh XML namespaces, so useful but ... sometimes ... so annoying.

Comment: @ta.speot.is Mostly annoying.  :-P

Comment: Thanks, JaredPar. Both methods that you suggested worked as you said.I should not have assumed that the MSDN sample code should work as is. I assumed it was more likely something with my setup.